# Purpose of resistor in pre_amp circuit

Tags: amplifier, resistors

Trying to understand this circuit. What is the resistor R1 for?

Wouldn't it just continuously supply voltage to the base and make it always "ON"?

[image: Text]

**Another version:**

[image: Text]

Comment: That's not a preamplifier.  It is driving the output (speaker) directly.  That makes it just an amplifier.

Comment: Transistors aren't just "on" or "off."

Comment: Learn more about this "biasing resistor" by searching for "biasing an NPN transistor". Do realize that you cannot expect this simple circuit to drive an 8 ohm loudspeaker properly. The volume will be quite low! If you want more volume, use a better design.

Comment: Try putting your circuit into the CircuitLab simulator (there's a button on the editor toolbar) and see what voltage you get on the collector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Trying to understand this circuit. What is the resistor R1 for?*

R1 biases the transistor so that it can be fed an AC signal via the capacitor C1. It also supplies some signal feedback to keep some semblance of slight quality about things but, as it stands it isn't HiFi (it's very LoFi) and impractical for most loudspeakers due to the DC current that passes through the speaker especially if you are trying to make the speaker operate at any loudness level higher than regular speech levels.

Comment: Oh wow, learned so much about biasing today. This source goes into some detail:

https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/transistor-biasing.html

Ah!  was wondering why not just hook R1 to Vcc, but  the collector voltage is providing the feedback, evidently. "Collector Feedback Biasing"

Comment: @drone6502 correct.